# Npgsql 5 a single select and multiple arguments

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, npgsql

I use Npqsql 5. Is there any way to retrieve values for many different arguments using a single select?
For example I want to run:

```
"select value from table where id=@id1"
"select value from table where id=@id4"
"select value from table where id=@id12"
```

but as a single query in order to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options that come to mind:

```
select value from table where id = @id1 or id = @id4 or id = @id12
```

or

```
select value from table where id in (@id1, @id4, @id12)
```